# Difference between range and selection in browser

Tags: javascript, html, browser, selection, range

I wanted to know the difference between the range and the selection object in JavaScript.

It appears to me that you could get the same functionality out of either of these two. In which case are there are any specific circumstances where you know which of the two to use?

Comment: Look at this table: http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/range_intro.html#link2.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

The fundamental difference is that a `Selection` represents the user's selection, while `Range` represents a continuous part of a document **independently of any visual representation**. A `Selection` can (almost) be expressed in terms of zero, one or more `Range`s but Ranges can also be created and modified completely independently of the selection.

There is some overlap in functionality: for example, `Selection`'s `deleteFromDocument()` is equivalent to calling `deleteContents()` on all of its component Ranges, and you can get the boundaries of the most recently selected Range in the selection using the `anchorNode`, `anchorOffset`, `focusNode` and `focusOffset` properties. However, there are some crucial differences:

- A `Selection` may contain multiple Ranges. However, the only major browser to support this currently is Firefox.
- A `Selection` may be "backwards", by which I mean that the end boundary of the selection (represented by `focusNode` and `focusOffset`) may occur earlier in the document than the start boundary (`anchorNode` and `anchorOffset`). A Range has no direction.
- `toString()` works differently. In most browsers (although notably not IE 9), calling `toString()` on a `Selection` object returns only the visible text that is selected, while calling `toString()` on a Range will return a concatenation of all text nodes within the range, including those within `<script>` elements and elements hidden via CSS.

Comment: I can't see much difference in toString method result. It's printing out the same results for both selection and range object.

Comment: @ParamSingh: I think that may still vary depending on browser. See http://jsbin.com/buhuvuworu/edit?html,js,output in Chrome, for example.

Comment: I made a [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/6z1k2tjr/) for demonstrating the dependency vs independency of visual representation of selection vs range, respectively.

Comment: the big difference is that Selection.toString() will preserve/insert whitepace between elements wheras Range.toString() just concatenates text nodes. This means that text nodes from within sibling elements will be concatenated with no extra whitespace.